# Looking for solid .Net client library for accessing WebDAV and SharePoint folders

Tags: c#, sharepoint, client, webdav

I have had mixed results in accessing WebDAV and SharePoint folders through Windows XP and Windows 7 using the standard .Net 4.0 libraries. Thus, I am looking for a solid .Net client library that I can use for accessing WebDAV and SharePoint folders.

I need to be able to enumerate folders and files, create folders, check for the existence of files and folders, as well as upload/download files. I need the library to work on both Windows XP and Windows 7.

In searching I have found three libraries so far:

http://www.independentsoft.de/webdav/index.html
http://www.webdavsystem.com/client
http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-webdav.php

I am interested if there are any other libraries I should consider and if anyone has had any positive/negative experience with any of these.

Thanks, Elan

Answer (score 1):

I use http://www.webdavsystem.com/client and http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-webdav.php successfully - both work fine.

The one from eldos is rather new and has still some smaller kinks to work around... regarding the network code eldos is a bit more flexible as you can plugin your own sockets layer.